# How to call .dll coded in vb6 from AutoHotkey Script?

Tags: vb6, autohotkey

I need to call .dll file from AutoHotkey but can not while I can access dll from vb6 as follows

```
//spaceCalculator.dll
Dim obj As New spaceCalculator.calculate
   msgbox obj.getData("shapes",2,100,100);
```

I want to call it from AutoHotkey as follows but throws error -3/-4. .dll in root folder of Script.

```
DllCall("spaceCalculator.dll\getUsageData","Str","Shapes","Float",2,"Float",100,"Float",100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that AutoHotKey can dll in which classes are defined like Vb6 and C# as follows

```
 obj:=CreateObject("projectName.ClassName"); // using CLSID
  obj.FunctionName(Parameters);
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Your VBScript uses COM. Your Autothing uses dynamic linking. This is what help says.

> **VBScript, JScript, and Component Object Model (COM)**
>
> VBScript and JScript may be embedded in a script via Windows Scripting for AutoHotkey, which also provides access to COM.
>
> Also, COM may be used directly via DllCall as demonstrated at www.autohotkey.com/wiki/index.php?title=COM_Wrappers.

Comment: I'm sure you aren't helpless

Answer (score 0):

I have a new ID. While help says you can use DllCall for COM it is very fiddly using COM via DLL function calls (and there's a lot you have to call like `CoInitilize` and `GetClassObject`) rather than the runtime doing all the grunt work.

Put your VBScript into your Autoit script as help suggests.

Note in VBScript you have to use late binding so

```
 Dim obj As New spaceCalculator.calculate
```

Becomes

```
 Set obj = CreateObject("spaceCalculator.calculate")
```

Although your objects looks wrong. Calculate looks like a method not an object itself.

Comment: Hi Triger
   Thans for reply, I put VBA code just for example how to call a function from a .dll
   But my job is to call same .dll from Authotey scripts which shows functions can not be accessible. Because it is inside a class...